# Atualizar definições de colunas e tabelas com Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring, multi-tenancy

Boa tarde.

Gostaria de saber e confirmar se tem alguma maneira de atualizar definições de tabela e coluna em cada schema utilizando o Hibernate.

Por enquanto, o que vi até agora foi que o Hibernate apenas cria tabelas e colunas, mas não deleta ou modifica as suas definições, como, por exemplo, o tamanho de um campo.

Já implementei o Flyway no aplicação e o mesmo está funcionando corretamente, porém a ideia é que isto seja feito sem criar um script SQL para percorrer os schemas e que o Hibernate identifique as definições que precisam ser alteradas, tabelas e campos que precisam ser criados e que aplique no banco para cada schema.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Eu entendo este recurso do Hibernate de criar ou atualizar esquema de banco de dados mais como um recurso de *design time* (onde se algo der errado ou a cada teste você simplesmente recria a base do zero) do que para atualizar bases em produção ou mesmo UAT. Não creio que seja função do aplicativo atualizar o seu banco porque infelizmente isso não é tarefa trivial nem livre de riscos. Atualizar o banco deve ser uma das tarefas de atualização de versão do aplicativo - ela pode e deve ser automatizada, mas deve ser feita por uma ferramenta especializada nisso (não é o caso do Hibernate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dentro do `persistence.xml` (ou `hibernate.cfg.xml` ou algum outro mecanismo equivalente) você pode definir a seguinte propriedade:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

- O valor "update" altera a estrutura do banco de dados para refletir as suas entidades Java.
- O valor "validate" não altera o banco de dados, apenas verifica se ele coincide com o especificado nas entidades. Caso não coincidir, uma exceção será lançada na inicialização.
- O valor "create" recria o banco de dados do zero, perdendo as informações lá existentes.
- O valor "create-drop" recria o banco de dados do zero, perdendo as informações lá existentes e também apaga tudo ao terminar de executar.

Portanto, me parece que o que lhe interessa é o "update". Mas devo avisar que não é recomendável utilizar-se isso em produção devido aos riscos inerentes de fazer-se modificações estruturais em tabelas sem o acompanhemento e planejamento manual e detalhado disso. Em ambiente de produção é recomendado usar apenas o "validate".

Comment: Muito obrigado Victor, quanto a propriedade hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto já conhecia, porém gostaria de saber se tem uma maneira, de utilizar isto por exemplo, e além de apenas criar tabelas e campos poder alterar também as definições de campos, como, por exemplo, o tamanho máximo do valor de uma coluna em um registro. É possível? Fiz testes aqui e está propriedade apenas cria, também vi no Stackoverflow em Inglês sobre isso. Essa é a principal questão.

Comment: @GiancarloGiulian Procurando rapidamente, achei alguém dizendo que o update não é bem suportado e o pessoal do hibernate confirmando: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2209886&sid=a3414397090d0ffd1338c19030bd0972#p2209886 - Entretanto isso foi em 2003 e é bem provável que a situação hoje seja bem diferente. Também achei esta pergunta abandonada no SOen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494157/what-is-exact-behavior-of-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-in-hibernate

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento, vou ver agora os links que você me passou.